# How can I cancel my scheduled mail in sendgrid?

Tags: sendgrid

I have scheduling mail using 'send_at' with future time. Now I want to cancel that scheduled mail. How can achieve this problem. Please provide the solutions for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you can cancel scheduled email in sendgrid.

[Here are the docs on how to do so](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/cancel_schedule_send.html)

Mainly.. "Scheduled sends can be cancelled, if you include a batch ID with your send. "

The docs show you how to add the batch ID to your outbound messages so you can cancel them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you cannot cancel scheduled messages at this time: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/scheduling_parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be doable , by creating and assigning batchid in request

1. Create batch ID,

   ```
    var batchId="";

    var client = new SendGridClient(apikey);

     var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: 
                  SendGridClient.Method.POST, urlPath: "mail/batch");

   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
      {
        JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
             batchId = (((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)joResponse["batch_id"]).Value).ToString();
        }
        return batchId;
   ```
2. Added batchId in Message body

   ```
    var msg = new SendGridMessage()
    {
        From = new EmailAddress("youremail@abc.com", ""),
        Subject = subject,
        PlainTextContent = message,
        HtmlContent = message,
        BatchId=batchId
    };


    var offset = new DateTimeOffset(timeToSend.Value);
    long sendAtUnixTime = offset.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    msg.SendAt = sendAtUnixTime;

    msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("recipientmail@abc.com"));
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
   ```

3)Cancel a scheduled batch

```
    var batchId="yur batch id"
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    string data = "{\"batch_id\":\"" + batchId +"\",\"status\": \"cancel\"}";
    var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.POST, 
    urlPath: "user/scheduled_sends", requestBody: data);
```

Note:

- *Make sure your api key has full access using sender grid option*.

  Setting --> apiKeys ---> edit Api key--> select "full access" and update
- *When a batch is canceled, all messages associated with that batch will stay in
  your sending queue. When their send at value is reached, they will be discarded.*
- for more detail please refer [enter link description here](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/cancel-scheduled-sends/cancel-or-pause-a-scheduled-send)